# Вопрос про try и except, python

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть такой код:

```
def cback():
    global txt,chg
    clor = "{}".format(txt.get())  

    try:
        if chg=="background":
            lbl.configure(bg=clor)
            clickb.configure(bg=clor,activebackground=clor)
            shop.configure(bg=clor,activebackground=clor)
            lear.configure(bg=clor,activebackground=clor)
            window.configure(bg=clor)

        if chg=="text":
            lbl.configure(fg=clor)
            clickb.configure(fg=clor)
            shop.configure(fg=clor)
            clear.configure(fg=clor)
            window.configure(fg=clor)
    except:messagebox.showerror("Не найден цвет.","Цвет не найден!")
```

При вводе не корректного цвета, выдается ошибка, вроде все окей, Но!

При вводе корректного цвета, выполняется функция(меняется цвет), но все равно выдается ошибка.

Где я допустил ошибку?

Answer (score 3):

**Короткий ответ:** `lear` вместо `clear` в комманде

```
lear.configure(bg=clor,activebackground=clor)
```

---

**Долгий ответ:**

Не давайте много кода до `try:` и не давайте там `if`.

Когда знаете, какую ошибку (исключение) вы хотите обработать (то узнаете, когда не используете try-except), примените ее класс в `except:`, для вашего кода **`except ValueError:`**, иначе может возникнуть **другая, какая-нибудь** ошибка, и вы все равно получите **ложное** сообщение

> «Не найден цвет».

Но и *точно такой случай ы вас настал,* потому что в вашем коде встретилась команда *с неправильным именем*

```
lear.configure(bg=clor,activebackground=clor)
```

вместо правильной

```
clear.configure(bg=clor,activebackground=clor)
```

и приводила к ошибке `NameError` (потому что имя `lear` не существует), но вы поймали **все** ошибки, выводя для всех одно и то же сообщение

> «Не найден цвет».

Измените ваш код — например так:

```
def cback():
    # global txt, chg               # не надо, потому что вы их не меняете
    clor = txt.get()                # не надо clor = "{}".format(txt.get()) 

    controls = [clickb, shop, clear, window]

    if chg == "background":
        try:
            lbl.configure(bg=clor)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Не найден цвет.", "Цвет не найден!")
            return
        for control in controls:
            control.configure(bg=clor, activebackground=clor)

    if chg == "text":
        try:
            lbl.configure(fg=clor)
        except ValueError:
            messagebox.showerror("Не найден цвет.", "Цвет не найден!")
            return
        for control in controls:
            control.configure(fg=clor)
```

Comment: Ваш код не работает, при  вводе корректного цвета, ошибка что фунции -fg не найдено.
При вводе корректного цвета, пишет что цвет не найден.

Comment: Я тестировал его, у меня работает, и для корректного цвета, и для некорректного. Скопируйте мой код через буфер, чтобы не было ошибок.